# Find a distance between point clouds efficiently

Tags: algorithm, 3d, point-clouds, kdtree

I have 2 point clouds (a set of points in 3D space) and an iterative algorithm. One of the clouds (let's call it *A*) is constant on each iteration and another (call it *B(i)*) is slightly different on each iteration (it means that *B(i+1)* differs from *B(i)* only in a few points). On every iteration *i* for each point from *A* my algorithm should find closest point from *B(i)*.

My question is: how can I compute these distances in a fastest way possible?

Here is what I've already tried:

- Brute force computing (compute all distances for each pair of points from *A* and *B(i)*) - absolutely inefficient.
- On each iteration build a KD-tree for *B(i)* and then find closest points for each point from *A* - faster then brute force, but still computationally expensive (because I should rebuild KD-tree on each iteration).

It seems like I should utilize a fact that *B(i)* and *B(i+1)* differs only slightly from each other, but I still can't come up with a good solution. Thank you in advance.

Comment: 1. Do the clouds represent two non-intersecting solid objects?  If so, you should be able to reduce A to the set of points to those that on its convex hull.  2. Why not build the k-d tree for A?  Then, instead of iterating through points in A and finding the closest point in B, you iterate through the points in B and find the closest point in A.  Finding the closest point in A would be accelerated by the k-d tree, and that you had to build just one  time.

Comment: Unfortunately, these clouds are not solid object and they do intersect. I can't just switch A and B(i) as you suggested, because I need to know a distance from every point of A to B(i), but in this solution I wouldn't get that for points of A that are far from B(i).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each point in A, keep a record of which point was closest in the previous iteration B(i).

At iteration i+1, make a list of each point in B that was deleted or changed between i and i+1, and also each new point in B.

For each point in A:

- If the previous closest point in B was not changed or removed, then you only need to compute the distance from A to the closest of the new points in B(i+1) and check against the previous closest in B(i).
- If the previous closest point in B(i) was changed or removed, then you need to compute the closest distance from A to any of the points in B(i+1)

You can use a KD-tree or whatever spatial data structure you like to speed this up, but the optimization comes from the first case. Note that a KD-tree allows removal so you don't need to rebuild the whole thing from scratch each iteration.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that idea, I'll try to implement this!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Wasserstein distance to measure the distance between two sets of point clouds. In this case you think about each point cloud as being drawn from a probability distribution.